# 2D array has more columns then expected

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to copy a 2D array (3x5) filled with the numbers from 0 to 14 into a 1D array. It has worked when I created static arrays. 
I wanted to do the same with some dynamically allocated arrays and ran into a problem. Instead of 3 rows and 5 columns the array seems to have 8 columns and gives me an output with some random values.

I would be glad if someone could help me. I tried to fix it for 2 hours, but I can't figure out where the problem is.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define M 3
#define N 5

void output(int* Array, int m, int n)
{
        for( int i=0 ; i<m ; i++)
        {
            for( int j=0 ; j<n ; j++)
                printf("\t%d", Array[i*n + j]);

            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
}

void array_copy(int* Array_2d, int* Array_1d, int m, int n)
{
    for( int i=0; i<m; i++)
        for( int j=0; j<n; j++)
            Array_1d[i*n + j] = Array_2d[i*n + j];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //int Array_basis [M][N] = { { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14} };

    //int Array_result [M*N];

    int** Array_basis;                              // Create 2D Array
    Array_basis = malloc(M*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
        Array_basis[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0; i<M; i++)                          // This part should fill the array with numbers from 0 to 14, but e.g. Array_basis [0][7] = 0; is also working, so that some values from [M][5] to [M]{7] are random
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
            Array_basis[i][j] = i*N + j; 

    int* Array_result = malloc((M*N*sizeof(int)));  //  Create 1D Array

    output(*Array_basis, M, N);

    array_copy (*Array_basis, Array_result, M, N);

    output(Array_result, M, N);
}
```

I would like the output to look like this:

[image]

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output(*Array_basis, M, N);
```

It's allocate with `N * sizeof int` (in your code `Array_basis[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int));`). So when you use it in `output` function, you went out of the memory that you allocated for it before (because the memory of `int** Array_basis` will not be contiguous as the comment in your question).

You should change the `output` function to;

```
void output(int *array, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Then, in main function, when you call this function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    output(Array_basis[i], N); // print each row here
    printf("\n");
}
// for Array_result
output(Array_result, M*N);
```

The copy function should change to:

```
void array_copy(int** Array_2d, int* Array_1d, int m, int n)
{
    for( int i=0; i<m; i++)
        for( int j=0; j<n; j++)
            Array_1d[i*n + j] = Array_2d[i][j];
}
```

It means you copy the values of 2D array to 1D array.

Then in main function:

```
array_copy (Array_basis, Array_result, M, N);
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot for taking the time!